# Extract multiple substring in the same line

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to build a logparser but i'm stuck.
Right now my program  goes trough multiple file in a directory and read all the file line by line.
I was able to identify the substring i was looking for "fct=" and extract the value next to the "=" using delimiter but i notice that when i have a line with more then one "fct=" it doesnt see it.

So i restart my code and i find a way to get the index position of all occurence of fct= in the same line  using an extension method that put the index in a list but i dont see how i can use this list to get the value next to the "=" and using my delimiter.

How can i extract the value next to the "=" knowing the start position of "fct=" and the delimiter at the end of the wanted value?

I'm starting in C# so let me know if i can give you more information.
Thanks,

Here's an example of what i would like to parse:

```xml
<dat>FCT=10019,XN=KEY,CN=ROHWEPJQSKAUMDUC FCT=666</dat></logurl>
<dat>XN=KEY,CN=RTU FCT=4515</dat></logurl>
<dat>XN=KEY,CN=RT</dat></logurl>
```

I would like t retrieve 10019,666 and 4515.

```
namespace LogParserV1
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int counter = 0;
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:/LogParser/LogParserV1", "*.txt");
        string fctnumber;
        char[] enddelimiter = { '<', ',', '&', ':', ' ', '\\', '\'' };

        foreach (string fileName in dirs)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);

            {
                String lineRead;
                while ((lineRead = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    if (lineRead.Contains("fct="))
                    {
                        List<int> list = MyExtensions.GetPositions(lineRead, "fct");
                        //int start = lineRead.IndexOf("fct=") + 4;
                       // int end = lineRead.IndexOfAny(enddelimiter, start);
                        //string result = lineRead.Substring(start, end - start);

                        fctnumber = result;

                        //System.Console.WriteLine(fctnumber);
                        list.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
                    }
                    // affiche tout les ligne System.Console.WriteLine(lineRead);
                    counter++;
                }
                System.Console.WriteLine(fileName);

                sr.Close();
            }
        }

        // Suspend the screen.  
        System.Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
}


namespace ExtensionMethods
{
public  class MyExtensions
{
    public static List<int> GetPositions(string source, string searchString)
    {
        List<int> ret = new List<int>();
        int len = searchString.Length;
        int start = -len;
        while (true)
        {
            start = source.IndexOf(searchString, start + len);
            if (start == -1)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                ret.Add(start);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you add some lines you want to parse and the expected output. Please do not forget to add worst case examples

Comment: The sample data smells like xml but I miss the leading logurl tag. Is that also missing in the original data?

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your code a lot by using `Regex` pattern matching instead.

The following pattern: `(?<=FCT=)[0-9]*` will match any group of digits preceded by `FCT=`.

[Try it out](https://regex101.com/r/ay5Pih/1)

This enables us to do the following:

```
string input = "<dat>FCT=10019,XN=KEY,CN=ROHWEPJQSKAUMDUC FCT=666</dat></logurl>...";
string pattern = "(?<=FCT=)[0-9]*";
var values = Regex.Matches(input, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this solution with your data, and it gives me the expected results (10019,666 and 4515)

```cs
string data = @"<dat>FCT=10019,XN=KEY,CN=ROHWEPJQSKAUMDUC FCT=666</dat></logurl>
                <dat>XN=KEY,CN=RTU FCT=4515</dat></logurl>
                <dat>XN=KEY,CN=RT</dat></logurl>";

char[] delimiters = { '<', ',', '&', ':', ' ', '\\', '\'' };

Regex regex = new Regex("fct=(.+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var values = data.Split(delimiters).Select(x => regex.Match(x).Groups[1].Value);
values = values.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));

values.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

I hope my solution will be helpful, let me know.

Comment: This seems to be working do you know if there any downside using Regex? Thanks

Comment: Hello Joel, the only downside that comes me to mind is the readibility because a lot of very complex information is compacted into a few characters. But I think that the saving in code lines outweights this downside.

Answer (score 1):

Below code is usefull to extract the repeated words with linq in text

```
string text = "Hi Naresh, How are you. You will be next Super man";
    IEnumerable<string> strings = text.Split(' ').ToList();
    var result = strings.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new {str = Regex.Replace(x.ToLowerInvariant(), @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", ""), count = Regex.Matches(text.ToLowerInvariant(), @"\b" + Regex.Escape(Regex.Replace(x.ToLowerInvariant(), @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "")) + @"\b").Count}).Where(x=>x.count>1).GroupBy(x => x.str).Select(x => x.First());
    foreach(var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.str +" = "+item.count.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the line by string[]

```
char[] enddelimiter = { '<', ',', '&', ':', ' ', '\\', '\'' };
while ((lineRead = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
               string[] parts1 = lineRead.Split(new string[] { "fct=" },StringSplitOptions.None);

                if(parts1.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach(string _ar in parts1)
            {
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ar))
                {
                    if(_ar.IndexOfAny(enddelimiter) > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(_ar.Substring(0, _ar.IndexOfAny(enddelimiter)));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(_ar);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: This would seperate the entries if there would only be `fct=valuefct=value....` . The example `<dat>XN=KEY,CN=RTU FCT=4515</dat></logurl>` would generate `<dat>XN=KEY,CN=RTU` and `4515</dat></logurl>` which is not the desired result

Answer (score 0):

As always, break down the porblem into smaller bits. See if the following methods help in any way. Tying it up to your code is left as an excercise.

```
private const string Prefix = "fct=";

//make delimiter look up fast
private static HashSet<char> endDelimiters = 
    new HashSet<char>(new [] { '<', ',', '&', ':', ' ', '\\', '\'' });

private static string[] GetAllFctFields(string line) =>
    line.Split(new string[] { Prefix });

private static bool TryGetValue(string delimitedString, out string value)
{
    var buffer = new StringBuilder(delimitedString.Length);

    foreach (var c in delimitedString)
    {
        if (endDelimiters.Contains(c)) 
            break;

        buffer.Append(c);
    }

    //I'm assuming that no end delimiter is a format error.
    //Modify according to requirements
    if (buffer.Length == delimitedString.Length) 
    {
        value = null;
        return false;
    }

    value = buffer.ToString();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] enddelimiter = { '<', ',', '&', ':', ' ', '\\', '\'' };
        var fct = "fct=";

        var lineRead = "fct=value1,useless text fct=vfct=alue2,fct=value3";

        var values = new List<string>();
        int start = lineRead.IndexOf(fct);
        while(start != -1)
        {
            start += fct.Length;
            int end = lineRead.IndexOfAny(enddelimiter, start);
            if (end == -1)
                end = lineRead.Length;
            string result = lineRead.Substring(start, end - start);
            values.Add(result);
            start = lineRead.IndexOf(fct, end);
        }
        values.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
}
```